# X Number Of Rows Into One Row Based On One Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been asked to display X number of rows, into a row that is going across with results. So for example :-

The Data

```
 Tency Number| ClientNo  |  Name |  DOB       | Prim Client |  Rent
 10001          20          Joe    01/10/1900    Y            100 
 10001          21          bob    01/10/1901    N            100 
 10001          26          jim    01/10/1902    n            100
```

The format the user would like is

```
Tency Number | ClientNo | Name | DOB        | Prim Client | Rent | Client2 | DOB 2|
10001          20          Joe   01/10/1900      Y           100 |   Bob   01/10/1901 | Jim | 01/10/1902
```

We haven't got a pre defined number of client linked to Tenacy Number. I'm lost at what to use to achieve this. There is nothing there to pivot the table, and I used STUFF to link all the client into one column on the row (But they didn't want that).

Is this possible? And if so how would I achieve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL you would need would be something like:

```
SELECT  TencyNumber, 
        ClientNo = MIN(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN ClientNo END),
        Client1 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN Name END),
        DOB1 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN DOB END),
        Client2 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 2 THEN Name END),
        DOB2 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 2 THEN DOB END),
        Client3 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 3 THEN Name END),
        DOB3 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 3 THEN DOB END)
FROM (  SELECT  TencyNumber, 
                ClientNo,
                Name,
                DOB, 
                PrimClient,
                Rent,
                RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TencyNumber ORDER BY Name)
        FROM    T
    ) c
GROUP BY TencyNumber;
```

But since you have an unknown number of clients, you would need to build the SQL dynamically:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT   @SQL = @SQL + 
                    ',Client' + RowNum + ' = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = ' + RowNum + ' THEN Name END)
                    ,DOB' + RowNum + ' = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = ' + RowNum + ' THEN DOB END)'
FROM    (   SELECT  RowNum = CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TencyNumber ORDER BY Name) AS VARCHAR(10))
            FROM    T
        ) c;

SET @SQL = 'SELECT TencyNumber, ClientNo = MIN(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN ClientNo END) ' + @SQL + '
            FROM (  SELECT  TencyNumber, 
                            ClientNo,
                            Name,
                            DOB, 
                            PrimClient,
                            Rent,
                            RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TencyNumber ORDER BY Name)
                    FROM    T
                ) c
            GROUP BY TencyNumber;';
EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b670b/2)**